# IOS: is it possible to bind one story board view controller to several different classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I know it's possible to attach a custom view controller class to several different view controllers on a storyboard, but can it be done in the other direction; that is, depending on the situation, I want to bind different custom classes to a single view controller on the storyboard that will be instantiated using:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]
```

background: I used to have several view controllers on my storyboard that are almost identical. In fact, the custom classes that they each bind to are very similar as well. In an effort to clean this up, I refactored my custom classes into one base class and several subclasses. I then removed all the similar view controllers from the storyboard leaving only one which I've bounded to my base class. I then call:

```
MySubclass* mySubclass = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardControllerBoundToBaseClass"];
```

Unfortunately, my subclass code is being ignored and only the base class code is ever run. Does anyone know how I can make it work without duplicating view controllers on the storyboard and binding each one to a different subclass?

Comment: <p>See the answer in this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/42234429/6386213">link</a>.</p> <p>Hope this helps.</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using subclassing, I figure I can reuse a view controller on the storyboard by using a delegate/proxy model. More specifically, I can bind the storyboard's view controller to a custom class that delegates all of its methods/events to others classes to handle. This isn't as elegant as subclassing but at least I can keep my storyboard leaner, not having to keep several copies of pretty much the same view controller. Plus, I won't need to duplicate future changes to every copy of these controllers to boot.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible.  Just because you say MySubclass *object = something doesn't magically convert object into a MySubclass object.  It's stored in the storyboard with whatever class was assigned at storyboard compile time.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

As guylegend writes. Apple doesn't support the way to do that. There are many workarounds e.g. with delegates but I finally found the answer and answered in another topic. Hope it helps!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103618/1943053